# Can't get request data

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

[I have a viewset and a function with an additional address (decorator @action)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxukH.png). In the serializer, [I define an additional field through the SerializerMethodFieldenter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXC45.png), and in order to define it, I need to know the user data through request.user. So the problem is, when the request goes through the viewset address (.../api/users/), everything is fine, but when it go through my additional address (.../api/users/subscriptions) there is no request data and i get this **user = self.context.get('request').user
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'user'**

The serializer has no information about the request that went through @action

[viewset url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86kCv.png)

[@action url, self.context is empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bp03b.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple way using your code, just change in `UserViewSet` to:

```
.....
context = {
    'request': self.request,
    'format': self.format_kwarg,
    'view': self
}
serializer = UserSerializer(users, many=True, context=context)
.....
```

Check https://www.cdrf.co/3.14/rest_framework.viewsets/ModelViewSet.html method: `get_serializer_context`